# S3 access denied in flutter app while using aws amplify storage

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I have been using AWS amplify storage to store my JSON files. Also I have done all the setup needed to perform crud operations to a bucket in s3. All of a sudden, I am not able to retrive data from the s3 bucket and I am getting an error `Error listing files: S3 access denied when making the API call.`

This is the policy that is attached to the IAM user and I have block all public access on for my bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::restroapp2ea8e37478e64ba88fbd570b81391d93153108-dev"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::restroapp2ea8e37478e64ba88fbd570b81391d93153108-dev/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to list the files in form of a list tile, which was working till yesterday. And there are no external bucket policies attached

Comment: Hey, yes I did solve it

Comment: what was the bug? i have the same issue, app can download on iOS but not on android!